# Android studio name validation

Tags: java, android, android-studio, validation

I'm comming with a little question here. I need to do something to validate the a name in the registration form, until now I did this :

> if(TextUtils.isEmpty(textFullName) )

and this

> else if(!textFullName.matches("[a-zA-Z ]+"))

but those are for empty and alphabetic characters, the problem is that I can't have spaces between names like : " Bill Bob" ( it works only if they are together : "BillBob" ) and another thing is that I want this symbol : "-" , because some names have it, like : "Bill-Bob".
Thank you for helping me out!

Comment: You have a space after Z in the RE. Should be fine for match names with spaces. You may add a - to the square brackets to match hyphens. [a-zA-Z -]+

Answer (score 0):

The regex should also include `space(\\s)` and `-`

```
else if(!textFullName.matches("[a-zA-Z\\s-]+"))
```